# Knockout "with" binding, and using array index accessor

Tags: knockout.js

I'm trying to use the following 'with' binding in knockout:

```
<td data-bind="with: $data.tiers()[$parents[1].Index]">
    ...
</td>
```

But I'm getting the error "Unexpected token );". If I just use `$data.tiers()[0]` it works, and I know that `$parents[1].Index` evaluates to a number. Is this just a limitation of knockout, that you can't use nested index accessors?

Comment: Which KO version are you using? Can you try it with the latest 3.0 RC version http://knockoutjs.com/downloads/knockout-3.0.0rc.js?

Comment: I'm using 2.2.1. I just tried 3.0 RC, but it broke a whole host of other stuff, so I think I'll give that a miss. :P

Comment: Every day I see people here at SO that put alot of code in the View, it makes me sad because it defeats the purpose of MVVM

Comment: Yeah, I am trying to minimise the code as much as I can, but it's quite a complex view, so it's quite hard to avoid. I'm fairly new to KO as well.

Comment: This is a known issue: [ko.expressionRewriting.preProcessBindings failing at array expressions](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/911) which should be fixed in version 3.0. You can find a possible workaround in the linked github issue.

Comment: Its more of a MVVM / Object structure problem than a KO problem actually. $data.tiers()[$parents[1].Index] Is not very object oriented, shouldn't the $data context only hold a tier object for the current scope instead. Cleaner and testable etc

Comment: Thanks nemesv, that workaround fixed it. :) Anders, you're probably right. I was initially using a foreach loop and checking the index, but saw this method of cutting out 2 lines of code. ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue: [ko.expressionRewriting.preProcessBindings failing at array expressions](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/911) which was be fixed in KO version 3.0.

If you cannot upgrade to 3.0 you can find a possible workaround in the linked github issue, so you just need to change your expression to:

```
<td data-bind="with: ($data.tiers()[$parents[1].Index])">
    ...
</td>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Re9pb/).